# how to download images via python by taking url form a excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel sheet with url of images can I use a python script to download them all? if yes then what will be the code

Comment: Do you need to save those images locally?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide your code attemts.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ Yes I want to

Comment: @blondelg im kind of newbie to python but I was doing this downloading thing manually . So I just got curious if we could automate this with python

Comment: Tried below answer?

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ yeah its working

Comment: Ok great.. please mark it as an accepted answer if it solved all your queries, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
'''Do pip install requests if requests module was not installed'''
import requests

listUrls = ['https://nandyembedly.herokuapp.com/static/favicon.ico']
for url in listUrls:
    res = requests.get(url).content
    with open(f"{url.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]}.png",'wb') as f:
        f.write(res)
```